# JavaScript .click() not changing CSS "display" property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar which on click to make visible a div that has been previously hidden with `display: none`.  Below is what I have till now:

Navigation bar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#home').click(function() {
        $('.site-content').html($('#home_wrap'));
      });

      $('#skills').click(function() {
        $('.site-content').html($('#skills_wrap'));
      });
```

```css
#home_wrap,
#skills_wrap {
  display: none;
}

.site-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav__content">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__list-item" id="home" href="#">Home</li>
    <li class="nav__list-item" id="skills" href="#">Skills</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As this is an old project, I think the navigation used to work but now it's not.

Comment: You don't seem to have a `.site-content` element. Is there an error in your console? Does the code do *anything*?

Comment: You're setting those divs to `display:none` in the CSS - but are not making them visible in your script when they're loaded. I would recommend maybe keeping those divs visible inside of a hidden DIV. That way you don't have to show/hide the individual divs each time.

Comment: The idea is that all content is loaded when you open the website but invisible. Once you click on the navigation bar for example on "skills" to make the content from that div visible. The JavaScript is "supposed" to apply .site-content to #skills_wrap when clicked on "Skills" in the navigation bar.

Comment: The #home_wrap and #skills_wrap elements are not present in your HTML snippet. Regardless, the .html() method will not change the visibility of the element. You need to use .show() or the .css() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use: $('#home_wrap').show()